# Is there any scenario where an iterator can do something an iteratee+enumerator cannot

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iterator

I'm looking into using alternatives to iterators in my code base, and was recently introduced to iteratee as a potential solution.  Iteratee come from functional programming and is an abstraction to incrementally process over a stream of data.

Is there any scenario where an iterator can do something an iteratee+enumerator cannot, or where you would prefer an iterator over an iteratee?

Comment: You might find this article useful https://alexn.org/blog/2018/02/12/in-defense-oofp.html#h4-3